# Vectorize() vs apply()

Tags: r, vectorization, apply, mapply

The `Vectorize()` and the `apply()` functions in `R` can often be used to accomplish the same goal.  I usually prefer vectorizing a function for readability reasons, because the main calling function is related to the task at hand while `sapply` is not.  It is also useful to `Vectorize()` when I am going to be using that vectorized function multiple times in my R code.  For instance:

```
a <- 100
b <- 200
c <- 300
varnames <- c('a', 'b', 'c')

getv <- Vectorize(get)
getv(varnames)
```

vs

```
sapply(varnames, get)
```

However, at least on SO I rarely see examples with `Vectorize()` in the solution, only `apply()` (or one of it's siblings).  Are there any efficiency issues or other legitimate concerns with `Vectorize()` that make `apply()` a better option?

Comment: Hmm... did you run your own example? I'm already seeing one problem with `Vectorize` there...

Comment: Well I guess that starts to answer my question.  Under the hood it looks like `Vectorize()` is just a wrapper for `mapply()`.

Comment: Since your example is obviated with `mget()`, can you rewrite with a better example?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Vectorize` is just a wrapper for `mapply`. It just builds you an `mapply` loop for whatever function you feed it. Thus there are often easier things do to than `Vectorize()` it and the explicit `*apply` solutions end up being computationally equivalent or perhaps superior.

Also, for your specific example, you've heard of `mget`, right?

Answer (score 14):

To add to Thomas's answer. Maybe also speed?

```
    # install.packages(c("microbenchmark", "stringr"), dependencies = TRUE)
require(microbenchmark)
require(stringr)

Vect <- function(x) { getv <- Vectorize(get); getv(x) }
sapp <- function(x) sapply(x, get)
mgett <- function(x) mget(x)
res <- microbenchmark(Vect(varnames), sapp(varnames), mget(varnames), times = 15)

## Print results:
print(res)
Unit: microseconds
           expr     min       lq  median       uq     max neval
 Vect(varnames) 106.752 110.3845 116.050 122.9030 246.934    15
 sapp(varnames)  31.731  33.8680  36.199  36.7810 100.712    15
 mget(varnames)   2.856   3.1930   3.732   4.1185  13.624    15


### Plot results:
boxplot(res)
```

[image]

Comment: Typo on `mget` vs `mgett`