# Vectorizing this function in R

Tags: r

Hi so I have the following function:

```
kde.cv = function(X,s)    {
  l = length(X)

  log.fhat.vector = c()
  for (i in 1:l) {
    current.log.fhat = log ( kde(X[i],X[-i],s) )
    log.fhat.vector[i] = current.log.fhat
  }

  CV.score = sum(log.fhat.vector)

  return(CV.score)
}
```

I'd like to vectorize this without using any for loops or apply statements, can't seem to get around doing so. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Given the responses, here are my answers to the questions posed.

Given requests for clarification, I will elaborate on the function inputs and on the user defined function inside the function given. So X here is a dataset in the form of a vector, specifically, a vector of length 7 in the dataset I used as an input to this function. The X I used this function for is c(-1.1653, -0.7538, -1.3218, -2.3394, -1.9766, -1.8718, -1.5041). s is a single scalar point set at 0.2 for the use of this function. kde is a user - defined function that I wrote. Here is the implementation:

```
kde = function(x,X,s){
  l = length(x)   
  b = matrix(X,l,length(X),byrow = TRUE)
  c = x - b 
  phi.matrix = dnorm(c,0,s)
  d = rowMeans(phi.matrix)

  return(d)
}
```

in this function, X is the same vector of data points used in kde.cv. s is also the same scalar value of 0.2 used in kde.cv. x is a vector of evaluation points for the function, I used seq(-2.5, -0.5, by = 0.1).

Comment: please provide a more complete example that is reproducible. include a value for X and s so that we can use it to test your function. Also documentation on what are you trying to achieve will help the community.

Comment: @Juan Zamora I have edited my original post to give more details.  In terms of what I'm doing with this code:  kde is a function to fit a nonparametric density via a normal kernel on a dataset given by X using a vector of evaluation points x and bandwidth s. kde.cv is a function to conduct cross validation in order to choose an optimal bandwidth s.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `sapply`

```
kde.cv = function(X,s) 
    sum(sapply(1:length(X), function(i) log(kde(X[i], X[-i], s))))
```

Comment: The OP requests "I'd like to vectorize this without using any for loops or apply statements"

Comment: @SymbolixAU Without more information (in particular about what `kde` does) it's difficult to optimise the code. My answer should be faster than the original code attempt where `log.fhat.vector` is dynamically expanded in each step; the other answer also uses an apply method (`mapply` through `Vectorize`).

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, please provide a more complete example. For example, the `kde()` function. Is that a customized function?

Alternative to `sapply`, you can try `Vectorize()`. There are some examples you can find on stack overflow.

[Vectorize() vs apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081604/vectorize-vs-apply)

Here is an example

```
f1 <- function(x,y) return(x+y) 
f2 <- Vectorize(f1) 

f1(1:3, 2:4) 
[1] 3 5 7
f2(1:3, 2:4) 
[1] 3 5 7
```

and the second example

```
f1 <- function(x) 
{
 new.vector<-c()  
 for (i in 1:length(x)) 
 {
  new.vector[i]<-sum(x[i] + x[-i])
 }
 return(sum(new.vector))
}

f2<-function(x)
{
 f3<-function(y, i)
 {
  u<-sum(y[i]+y[-i])
  return(u)
 }
 f3.v<-Vectorize(function(i) f3(y = x, i=i))
 new.value<-f3.v(1:length(x))
 return(sum(new.value))
}

f1(1:3) 
[1] 24

f2(1:3) 
[1] 24
```

Note: Vectorize is a wrapper for `mapply`

**EDIT 1**

According to the response, I edited your `kde.cv` function.

```
kde.cv = function(X,s)    {
 l = length(X)

 log.fhat.vector = c()
 for (i in 1:l) {
  current.log.fhat = log ( kde(X[i],X[-i],s) )
  log.fhat.vector[i] = current.log.fhat
 }

 CV.score = sum(log.fhat.vector)

 return(CV.score)
}

kde = function(x,X,s){
 l = length(x)   
 b = matrix(X,l,length(X),byrow = TRUE)
 c = x - b 
 phi.matrix = dnorm(c,0,s)
 d = rowMeans(phi.matrix)

 return(d)
}


##### Vectorize kde.cv ######

kde.cv.v = function(X,s)   
{
 log.fhat.vector = c()

 kde.v<-Vectorize(function(i) kde(X[i], X[-i], s))

 CV.score <- sum(log(kde.v(1:length(X))))

 return(CV.score)
}

X<-c(-1.1653, -0.7538, -1.3218, -2.3394, -1.9766, -1.8718, -1.5041)
s<-0.2
x<-seq(-2.5, -0.5, by = 0.1)

kde.cv(X, s)
[1] -10.18278

kde.cv.v(X, s)
[1] -10.18278
```

**EDIT 2**

Well, I think the following function may match your requirement. BTW, since the little `x` is not used in your `kde.cv`, I just edited both two functions

```
kde.cv.2 <- function(X,s)    
{
 log.fhat.vector<-log(kde.2(X, s))
 CV.score = sum(log.fhat.vector)
 return(CV.score)
}

kde.2<-function(X, s)
{
 l <- length(X)  
 b <- matrix(rep(X, l), l, l, byrow = T)
 c <- X - b
 diag(c) <- NA
 phi.matrix <- dnorm(c, 0, s)
 d <- rowMeans(phi.matrix, na.rm = T)
 return(d)
}

X<-c(-1.1653, -0.7538, -1.3218, -2.3394, -1.9766, -1.8718, -1.5041)
s<-0.2 

kde.cv(X,s)
[1] -10.18278

kde.cv.2(X, s)
[1] -10.18278
```

Comment: Yes Kde() is a user defined function I wrote. I have edited my original post to give more details.

Comment: @JaimeMelaraSosa So, in your `kde.cv` function, the first argument of `kde` you input is `X[i]`, which is a single value, while the first argument of `kde` should be a vector.

Comment: @JaimeMelaraSosa I assume `kde.cv` may match your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realize X[i] is a single value, but isin't a single value simply a vector of length 1? I dont think this matters too much since the function gives me the correct answer anyways. In terms of your rewritten kde.cv function using vectorize(), i'm not sure this is what i am looking for. When i say "vectorize" the function, I mean writing it using only vector/matrix operations without the use of loops or apply statements. I'm not too familiar with vectorize(), but isin't similar to apply() in that it is prewritten using loops as well?

Comment: @JaimeMelaraSosa Just a bit of strange consideration in my eye. BTW, the little `x` is not used, the `kde` function can use only two arguments.