# Are "self-contained" functions more efficient in R?

Tags: r, performance, function

I'm writing a function that needs to call a function `g` passed as a parameter to each element of a list, iteratively.

I'm wondering how to make this the fastest possible. I can achieve an acceptable speed using `Rcpp` and specific kind of `g` (writing everything in Cpp), but I can't figure out if I can reach similar speed passing an R function as argument.

Was doing some tests to figure out why R is slower and found some really unexpected results:

```
minus <- function(x) -x
minus_vec <- Vectorize(minus, "x")
```

Testing with some simple functions to invert signs.

```
f0 <- function(x) {
  sapply(x, minus)
}

f1 <- function(x) {
  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    x[i] <- -x[i]
  }
  x
}

f2 <- function(x) {
  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    x[i] <- minus(x[i])
  }
  x
}
```

I got the following results:

```
a <- 1:10^5
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(f0(a), f1(a), f2(a), minus_vec(a), minus(a))[,c(1,4)]

          test relative
1        f0(a)  454.842
2        f1(a)   25.579
3        f2(a)  178.211
4 minus_vec(a)  523.789
5     minus(a)    1.000
```

I would like some explanation on the following points:

- Why don't `f1` and `f2` have the same speed? Writing the piece of code `-x[i]` and calling the function `minus(x[i])` really should be so different when they do the exact same thing?
- Why is `f0` slower than `f2`? I always thought `apply` functions were more efficient than `for` loops, but never really understood why and now I even found a counter-example.
- Can I make a function as fast as `f1` using the function `minus` ?
- Why does vectorizing `minus` (unnecessary since `-` is already vectorized, but that might not be the case always) made it so bad?

Comment: `apply` are *not* always more efficient than self-written loops, it really depends on the taks and on how well the loop is written. Also, you could consider `vapply` which is the most efficient of the `apply` family.

Comment: for f1 and f2 whilst `-x` is a "built-in", `minus` is another function so there is another function call nested within every iteration.

Comment: No you probably can't make your edit function as fast as a "built-in" but you might make it a bit faster by using the JIT byte code `compiler` package - http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~luke/R/compiler/compiler.pdf

Comment: You are going to be led astray if you try to extrapolate techniques for speeding up something very basic like minus to anything of greater complexity. What does your function actually do?

Answer (score 2):

Not a full answer, but here are a few notes

**1** `minus(x)` vs `-x`: *Doing nothing is better than doing something*

Your function `minus` calls `` `-` ``, so the added step adds computation time. I honestly do not know the who's, what's and when's specifically, in other words I wouldn't know how much more computation time ought to be expected.

Here is an example highlighting it: we have four functions, all squaring numbers

```
fa <- function (n) n^2
fb <- function (n) fa(n)
fc <- function (n) fb(n)
fd <- function (n) fc(n)
Fa <- function (n) {
  for (i in seq_along(n)) n[i] <- fa(i)
  n
}
Fb <- function (n) {
  for (i in seq_along(n)) n[i] <- fb(i)
  n
}
Fc <- function (n) {
  for (i in seq_along(n)) n[i] <- fc(i)
  n
}
Fd <- function (n) {
  for (i in seq_along(n)) n[i] <- fd(i)
  n
}
```

And here are the benchmarking results

```
n <- 1:10^4
b <- benchmark(Fa(n),Fb(n),Fc(n),Fd(n), replications = 1000L)
b
#    test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1 Fa(n)         1000    3.93    1.000      3.85     0.00         NA        NA
# 2 Fb(n)         1000    7.08    1.802      6.94     0.02         NA        NA
# 3 Fc(n)         1000   10.16    2.585      9.94     0.06         NA        NA
# 4 Fd(n)         1000   13.68    3.481     13.56     0.00         NA        NA
# looks rather even
diff(b$elapsed)
# [1] 3.15 3.08 3.52
```

Now back to your `minus`function

```
a <- 1:10^5
b <- benchmark(f0(a), f1(a), f2(a), minus_vec(a), minus(a))          
b$elapsed[b$test == 'f2(a)'] - b$elapsed[b$test == 'f1(a)']    
# [1] 3.39
```

---

**2** `apply` vs `for` vs `Vectorize`:

@NavyCheng provided for some good material on the topic. Now my understanding is, the `apply` family (just like `Vectorize`) loops in `R` (whereas if I'm not mistaking the looping for `` `-` `` is done in `C`).

Again, I do not know about the exact details, but if `apply/Vectorize` use `R` loops, then, in theory (and *often* in practice), it is possible to write a proper `for` loop that will perform as good or better.

---

**3** *A Function as fast as* `f1`:

Ad-hoc, the closes I came up was by *cheating* using the `Rcpp` package. (*cheating* since one writes the function in `c++` first)

In **C++**

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector minusCpp(NumericVector x) {
  for (int k = 0; k < x.length(); ++k) {
    x[k] = -x[k];
  }
  return x;
}
```

Now to the bechmarks in `R`

```
a <- 1:10^5
b <- benchmark(f0(a), f1(a), f2(a), minus_vec(a), minus(a), minusCpp(a))          
b
#           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1        f0(a)          100    9.47       NA      9.22     0.01         NA        NA
# 2        f1(a)          100    0.53       NA      0.54     0.00         NA        NA
# 3        f2(a)          100    4.23       NA      4.24     0.00         NA        NA
# 5     minus(a)          100    0.00       NA      0.00     0.00         NA        NA
# 4 minus_vec(a)          100   10.42       NA     10.39     0.02         NA        NA
# 6  minusCpp(a)          100    0.05       NA      0.04     0.00         NA        NA
```

Comment: I think there is no way then. Sounds like looping in R and calling Rcpp function many times is slow, and looping in Rcpp and calling an R function from Rcpp many times also doesn't work. It's either all Rcpp or slow then.

Comment: @Freguglia Calling `R` functions in `Rcpp` is possible, see here http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/r-function-from-c++/ .

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned and the warning in that link states, calling `R` function from `Rcpp` isn't very efficient. "Calling a function is simple and tempting. It is also slow as there are overheads involved. And calling it repeatedly from inside your C++ code, possibly buried within several loops, is outright silly."

Comment: @Freguglia Yes, that's true. I interpreted your "doesn't work" literally.

Comment: @nate   *forloop* in R is faster than *apply family* in **sample** situation, and I find that *forloop*  with bad performance is because [data is not modified in place](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#modification). I hope this will help to complete this post.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore *-x[i]* and *minus(-x[i])*, and I summarize the four questions to two:

- Why *apply* family is slower than *forloop*?
- Why *Vectorize* is slower than *apply* family?

For the 1st question:

> The *apply* functions are designed to be convenient and clear to read, 
>   not necessarily fast.

and *apply* family will do more things than *forloop*,

> Also the sapply function first uses as.vector(unlist(...)) to convert anything to a vector, and in the end tries to simplify the answer into a suitable form.

You can't read [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/apply-is-slower-than-for-loop-td2284037.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533246/why-is-apply-method-slower-than-a-for-loop-in-r) for more detail.

For for 2rd question, it's because *Vectorize* is a wrapper of *mapply* and if you type `Vectorize` in Rstudio, you'll see the detail code. you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081604/vectorize-vs-apply) for more help.

Comment: I think it would be a better answer if you would summarise the argument found in those links. And to my best knowledge `Vectorize` is a wrapper around `mapply`.